# Apache Camel route requesting all entries from Paginated API

Tags: api, rest, pagination, apache-camel, fuseesb

there is a REST API allowing a POST to request items. The request payload is xml specifying items per page and the response payload also is xml containing total pages, total items, current page.

I'd like to collect all items and then proceed with another step.

There is any recommendation or best practices to implement that in elegant way?

The version of Camel is 2.15